# Searching for word in a file and converting it from lowercase to uppercase

Tags: linux, shell

I work on a shell script that it takes a wildcard from user and searches the matched words (for example; wildcard ar* finds article, are etc.) in the .txt files which are under current working directory . When it finds the words, it should converts them from lowercase to uppercase (ARTICLE, ARE...).

I generated a while loop to check all the words in a .txt file and a for loop to check all the .txt files. The while loop reads the .txt file word by word. It finds all the words which are matched with wildcard perfectly, however; I cannot convert them to uppercase.

```
....
while IFS= read -r word; do
    if [[ ${word,,} == ${string,,} ]] 
    then
        echo $word #to check the words          
        sed -i "s/${word}/${word^^}" $file                  
    fi
done
```

It prints all of the words perfectly but does not convert them to uppercase in the file and gives an error as;

```
"sed: -e expression #1, char 15: unterminated `s' command"
```

Comment: @Barmar for example if the user enters "ar*", it prints "article" that is found in any .txt file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the second `/` in the `s/old/new/` statement. You should also use the `g` modifier to replace all matches on a line.

```
sed -i "s/${word}/${word^^}/g" $file
```